# WebAPI 2.2 JSONFormatter includes NULL values in response

Tags: json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to get the JSONFormatter of a WebAPI 2.2 service to drop the NULL value fields from serialized JSON. Tried few solutions found on the web, but the response still contains the NULL values.

First I tried:

```
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings 
          = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
            {
               NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore
            };
```

Then I tried to replace the JSONFormatter altogether.

```
            var jsonformatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                SerializerSettings =
                {
                    DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                }
            };

            config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
            config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonformatter);
```

None of the methods did work. I still see the Null value properties in the generated JSON response.

These were done at the beginning of `WebApiConfig.Register(config)` method.

Classes returned by the API are generated from EF, and takes following format:

```
public partial class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirmType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FirmTypeId { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string HQCity { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> NetPatientRev { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NetworkId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NetworkParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller method:

```
    [Authorize]
    [EnableCors("*","*","*")]
    public class HospitalsController : ODataController

       [EnableQuery]
       public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntities()
       {
            return db.GetEntities(currentUserId);
       }

    }
```

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an instance of the object you're trying to serialize?

Comment: @JotaBe edited with more code samples.